# xargs lines containing -e and -n processed differently

Tags: echo, xargs

When running the following command with xargs (GNU findutils) 4.7.0

```
xargs -n1 <<<"-d -e -n -o"
```

I get this output

```
-d

-o
```

Why is -e and -n not present in the output?

Comment: because `echo -e` and `echo -n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man xargs`:

> [...] and executes the command (default is /bin/echo) [...]

So it runs:

```
echo -d
echo -e
echo -n
echo -o
```

But from `man echo`:

> ```
> -n     do not output the trailing newline
>
> -e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes
> ```

And `echo -n` outputs nothing, and `echo -e` outputs one empty newlines that you see in the output.

Comment: One way to get the desired output is to call printf instead of the default echo command ```xargs printf "%s\n" <<<"-d -e -n -o"```- That is what I ended up doing.

Comment: `to get the desired output` I do not understand, to get the same output you could `tr ' ' '\n'` or `printf "%s\n" -d -e -n -o` or `sed 's/ /\n/g' <<<"-d -e -n -o"` or realy just `echo $'-d\n-e\n-n\n-o'`. Ie. I see no value in `xargs` here.

Comment: You are right. There are better ways to achieve the same thing.